# Error: Expected expression before 'shared_mem_t'

Tags: c, function, memory, expression, shared-memory

I'm trying to compile this portion of my code and it's erroring saying that "expected expression before ‘shared_mem_t’", and I'm unsure how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
void* temp_monitor(void* ptr) {
    int thread = *((int*)ptr);
    int temperature;
    temperature = shared_mem_t->levels[thread].temp;

}
```

I tried reformatting, and just wanted the file to compile to move onto the next line so that my values would be carried over to the next function.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is `shared_mem_t`? Do you define it or include some header defining it? Sounds like a type name, not like a variable name.

Comment: I suppose the `shared_mem_t->levels[thread].temp` shall be grouped by the compiler as follows: `( ( shared_mem_t->levels ) [thread] ) .temp`. Is `shared_mem_t` a pointer to a struct that contains `levels`, which is an array of structs, where the struct contains member `temp`?

Answer (score 0):

The `shared_mem_t` identifier is almost certainly a *type,* given the `_t` suffix (using `<description>_t` and `t<Description>` are two *very* common ways to name types).

If so, that's not the correct use for it. You need a *variable* that can be dereferenced, something like:

```c
shared_memory = some_function_returning_pointer_variable_into_shared_memory();
temperature = shared_memory->levels[thread].temp;
```